# ASP.net Core 2.1 MVC - Scaffolding doesn't use Tag Helpers?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, html-helper, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm making an ASP.net Core 2.1 MVC website as I want to explore Tag Helpers.

However, when I Add a View to a Controller ActionMethod with a List Template, rather than scaffolding Tag Helpers a bit like this:

```
<a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a> |
<a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Details</a> |
<a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Delete</a>
```

It just scaffolds HTML helpers - exactly the same as with an MVC 5 site:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
```

Although it does include a single tag helper at the top of the file:

```
<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
```

Is this just an oversight from Microsoft?  (I find them easier to read - and I got the impression Tag Helpers supersede HTML helpers as they are less jarring etc).

Is there a way you can force Tag Helpers, or does anyone know if Microsoft have plans to update the scaffolding to use them in future?

Seems like a strange oversight?

Thanks.

Comment: I found this issue on github. https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/issues/580

Comment: Thanks I've now commented.